# Auto code blocking/syntax highlighter in slate.js

Tags: reactjs, slate.js

I'm creating a markdown editor for a chat I am making, and I want to render, in addition, code blocks. I already have the basics of markdown, for example, italics, bold fonts, and `single code blocks`, how would I do the same for syntax highlighting?

```js
  function greeting(hello) {
    return console.log(hello);
 }
```

The code above is a reference for what I want, and please use this for an example:
https://exuberant-forested-roo.glitch.me/

I've tried adding a new element type, with its corresponding phrase which in this case would be: '```', with no prevail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.